# XtraReports Null Reference Exception

Tags: data-binding, reporting, devexpress

Anyone who used the XtraReports, i have created a databinding on one of my LINQ to SQL objects and dragged some properties over the report, but when i set the datasource to an object i get NullReferenceException in ShowPreview() method. If i don't set the DataSource i see the preview correctly (basically only the picturebox i set as background). Could this happen because some values are null? even i don't use them? if so is true, this is so pity.

The Exception does not help more.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can utilize LINQ to SQL API to bind an XtraReport document to data.

Check out the sample project located in this issue:
http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/p/S30767.aspx

If you need more help, drop by the DevExpress support center:
http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/CreateIssue.aspx?issuetype=Question